# How to sweep along just one line?

Tags: cad

In fusion 360 when I select one line to sweep along it selects 2 lines instead of one, and the two lines are going in two directions from the area selected to sweep with so naturally the computer gets confused as it doesn't know witch of the two lines to sweep along. The two lines meet at the base to be swept along the line. When I go to select the correct line both lines highlight so I can't select just one.

Comment: Are both lines getting highlighted in one sketch?